# Keepalived_vrrp issue

Tags: keepalived, ipvs

## Configuration

- **debian version 9.7**
- **architecture ppc64**

## Issue

I am running `keepalived` and i am encountering an issue with IPVS, here are the logs :

> Feb 16 17:02:35 srv Keepalived_vrrp[10109]: IPVS: No such file or directory
>   Feb 16 17:02:35 srv Keepalived_vrrp[10109]: IPVS: Daemon has already run

And then, the `keepalived` daemon fails in loop zith the following log :

> Feb 16 17:02:37 srv-dhcp Keepalived_vrrp[10109]: pid 10122 exited with status 2

Any people that had the same issue ?